# Use the increment operator to modify an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm building a quiz engine using javascript. Rather than produce a score at the end, it produces a most popular outcome (think along the lines of 'which popstar are you', etc).

I presumed the best way to do this would be to give each possible outcome a score, and then store the scores as objects in an array, like so:

```
var outcomes = [
{name: "outcome1", score: 0},
{name: "outcome2", score: 0}
]
```

Each question would then modify the answer's score. I presumed the best way to do this would be to use the increment operator. However, I'm not completely sure how I'd specify which object's (or objects') score I wanted to increase.

Is there a means of using ++ to increase a specific object score within an array, or is there a much better way of doing this?

Comment: How will you be accessing the object in the array? By the `name` or by index? By index is simply `outcomes[0].score++`;

Comment: you hava key (name) value (score) pairs, so use a map to store them and access the one you want by name then use increase operator on the value

Comment: @Rhumborl that makes perfect sense. Can't believe I didn't think of that before. Thanks!